# Find a path within a specific cost

Tags: algorithm, graph, routes, dijkstra

There are many algorithms or policies for finding a path with minimum or maximum costs. But, it is hard to find an approach that can find a path **within** (or below) a required cost (RC), i.e., such an RC is not a minimum or maximum one, and the actual cost should less than such an RC.

I am looking for a feasible algorithm to find a path satisfying the two constraints:

1. The cost of such a path should be lower than the required cost.
2. The path from source to destination should contain as many hops as possible.

One example is as specified below,
e.g.,

The source is node A, the destination is node B; the required cost is 10. There are three pathes can be found from A to B:

```
 1. A --> C --> B;               cost is 5
 2. A --> C --> D --> B;         cost is 8
 3. A --> C --> D --> E --> B;   cost is 12
```

According to two mentioned constraints, `path 2 (A --> C --> D --> B; cost is 8)` is the best one, since the cost is 8 that less than the required cost 10, and path 2 is longer than path 1.

Hope I clearly explain my question.
Are there any released algorithms or methods to address this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is NP-complete. Specifically, this is a superproblem of the Hamiltonian path problem.

Comment: Looks NP-Complete indeed, you should ask your question on [or.se]

Comment: So, are loops allowed in your data, for example could I have A->C->D->C->D->B type structures? If this is the case I can keep going round the loop as many times as I choose and so construct many different length routes from the same nodes.  If you don't allow loops the problem becomes more tractable, look for Directed Acyclical Graph all path algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is well-known algorithm for this problem.

Let me just show you my snippet.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class info
{
    public:
        int hopcount;
    vector<int> path;
    int cost;
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    int s, e;
    vector<vector < int>> arr;
    cin >> n;
    arr.resize(n + 1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        arr[i].resize(n + 1);
    }
    cin >> s >> e;
    int pc;
    cin >> pc;
    for (int i = 0; i < pc; i++)
    {
        int source, def, cost;
        cin >> source >> def >> cost;
        arr[source][def] = cost;
    }
    int maxcost;
    cin >> maxcost;
    queue<info> q;
    q.push({1, {s}, 0 });
    int maxhopcount = -1;
    vector<int> hoppath;
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        auto qel = q.front();
        q.pop();
        int currentN = qel.path[qel.path.size() - 1];
        if (currentN == e)
        {
            if (qel.hopcount > maxhopcount)
            {
                maxhopcount = qel.hopcount;
                hoppath = qel.path;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            int sign = 0;
            for (auto c: qel.path)
            {
                if (c == i)
                {
                    sign = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (sign == 1) continue;
            if (arr[currentN][i] > 0)
            {
                info ni = qel;
                ni.path.push_back(i);
                ni.hopcount += 1;
                ni.cost += arr[currentN][i];
                if (ni.cost <= maxcost)
                {
                    q.push(ni);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << maxhopcount << endl;
    for (auto c: hoppath)
    {
        cout << c << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
/*
testcases
5
1 2
6
1 3 2
3 2 3
3 4 3
4 2 3
4 5 4
5 2 3
10

1 3 4 2
4
*/
```

I wrote a code with simple bfs method.

Writing Information about each step will solve this problem.

Let me know if there is any corner cases.

Comment: Either the code is not correct (= does not find optimal result) or it does not run in O(n^2) time for n vertices. In a fully-connected graph with n vertices there are O(n^2) edges, and there is a *much* larger number of candidate non-looping paths. Your algorithm cannot select the best one in only O(n^2).

Comment: I didn't thought about looping paths, and all loops are not considered on this code.

Comment: @KimMeo 
thanks very much for your codes, and I also do not consider the loops for my case. And I execute your codes, it works nicely. More, your algorithm is based on BFS, do you think if we adopt Dijkstra or A* to replace BFS, the program will also work and more quickly to find the solution in the case of A*?

Comment: @JunhuiJiang My opinion is NO. Because, A* and Dijkstra is greedy type of algorithm, they always choose the best way on 'Current Node'. But this problem is about getting longest hop count path in specific value, and I don't think it is possible to predict which node will have longer hop count toward the destination.