# Is it possible to determine the hop-count when performing Dijkstra?

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

Thank the [codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63976710/dijkstra-how-to-set-a-termination-condition-when-finding-the-destination) from @trincot I can modify the Dijkstra to obtain the shortest path between a given source node and destination node.
Moreover, I tried to count the hop when performing the Dijkstra to find the shortest path, when the hop-count exceeds the pre-defined Max_hop, the Dijkstra will be terminated, but I was failed.

Hop is defined as the (N - 1), where N is the number of vertices contained in the shortest paths.

Absolutely, after finding the shortest path, we can easily count the hop number. However, during the Dijkstra's path searching, can we count the hop between a given source and?

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush
def dijkstra(adjList, source, sink):
    n = len(adjList)   
    parent = [None]*n  
    heap = [(0,source,0)]
    explored_node=[]
    hop_count = 0
    Max_hop = 8    
    while heap:
        distance, current, came_from = heappop(heap)
        if parent[current] is not None:  # skip if already visited
            continue
        parent[current] = came_from  # this also marks the node as visited
        if sink and current == sink:  # only correct place to have terminating condition
            # build path
            path = [current]

            while current != source:
                current = parent[current]
                path.append(current)
            path.reverse()
            hop_count -=1
            print("Hop count is ",hop_count)
            
            return 1, distance, path
        for (neighbor, cost) in adjList[current]:
            if parent[neighbor] is None:  # not yet visited
                heappush(heap, (distance + cost, neighbor,  current))
                hop_count = hop_count + 1
                if hop_count > Max_hop:
                    print("Terminate")
adjList =[

[],

[[2,3],[4,11],[5,5]],
[[1,3],[3,5],[5,11],[6,7]],
[[2,5],[6,3]],
[[1,11],[5,15],[7,9]],
[[1,5],[2,11],[6,3],[7,6],[8,3],[9,9]],
[[2,7],[3,3],[5,3],[9,10]],
[[4,9],[5,6],[8,1],[10,11],[11,8]],
[[5,3],[7,1],[9,9],[11,11]],
[[5,9],[6,10],[8,9],[11,3],[12,8]],
[[7,11],[13,7],[14,3]],
[[7,8],[8,11],[9,3],[12,8],[14,6]],
[[9,8],[11,8],[15,11]],
[[10,7],[15,3]],
[[10,3],[11,6],[15,9]],
[[12,11],[13,3],[14,9]],
]

flag, dist, path = dijkstra(adjList,1,15)

print("found shortest path {}, which has a distance of {}".format(path, dist))
```

The graph of adjList is as shown: (the red line is the shortest path from 1 to 15)
[image]

I know this is incorrect since when Dijkstra iterates the neighbor, I make `hop_cout + 1` that represents the number of explored nodes rather than the hop_count.

In my opinion, there are two significant issues that need to be addressed.

1. When the shortest distance between a parent_node and a neighbor_node is determined, the hop_count can be added 1. But, Dijkstra finds the shortest path by iterating the neighbor nodes, and the array that stores the shortest distance is updated gradually during path searching. `How to determine Dijkstra has already found the shortest distance between a parent_node and a neighbor_node?`
2. Only condition 1 is not enough, even we can know when Dijkstra has found the shortest distance between two nodes, but how do we know whether the neighbor_node will be included in the shortest path between a given source and destination?

In summary, if we want to know the current hop-count during Dijkstra is running, we need to set hop_count +1, When the shortest path from the parent_node to the neighbor_node has been determined, and the neighbor_node will be included to the shortest path from the source to the destination node.

To better define the problem, as shown in this figure, the red line is the shortest path between `node 1` and `node 15`, the shortest path is `1 ->5 ->8 ->7 ->10 ->13 ->15`.

1. When `node 2` is explored and the shortest distance between `node 1` and
   `node 2` is determined as 3, the `hop_count` cannot be added 1 since
   `node 2` is not contained in the shortest path between 1 and 15.
2. When `node 5` is explored and the shortest distance between `node 1` and
   `node 5` is determined as 5, the `hop_count` **should be added 1** since
   `node 5` is contained in the shortest path between 1 and 15.

Is my understanding correct? May I hear your idea that "Is it possible to determine the hop-count when performing Dijkstra? "

Comment: Your first issue's answer is 'When the neighbor node's value is updated.'.
If you use prioirty queue for dijkstra algorithm, the node's value will be updated only once, and in that timing you can get the hop count from parent node.
About the second issue, i may say, it is not possible.
There is no ways to predict which node will be included in the shortest path.

Comment: @KimMeo I have reviewed the previous posts [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63609925/find-a-path-within-a-specific-cost/63610452#63610452). You implement BFS using C++, and in your codes, hop-count can be determined during the algorithm runtime. I think BFS and Dijkstra are similar, so it means by referencing your method it can also determine the hop-count during Dijkstra runtime?

Comment: Yes. But previous problem had one more condition:"Getting The Longest path". 
If you want to just find 'least value path', you can do this with dijkstra algorithm.
It would be very simple. Just add path array on prioirty queue structure and add hop number when any node is getting updated.

Comment: @KimMeo Yes, I want to find the 'least value path' between a given source and destination by using Dijkstra. Does "when any node is getting updated" mean a new node is explored? If so, the "hop number" here is not the real "hop-count", it would be the number of how many nodes are explored in a graph.

Comment: You want to get the 'least  value PATH' with dijkstra algorithm, am I understanding correctly? I'll just find the code.

Comment: @KimMeo Yes, get the 'least value PATH' with the Dijkstra algorithm while determining the hop-count during the Dijkstra runtime. When the hop-count exceeds the pre-defined Max_hop, the program will be terminated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the heap will have nodes that represent paths having varying lengths, you cannot hope to use one variable for the hop count. You would need to add the hop count as an additional information in the tuples that you put on the heap, as it is specific to each individual path.

Secondly, you would need to allow that different paths to the same node are allowed to be extended further, as some of these might drop out because of the hop limit, while another may stay under that limit. So concretely, when a more costly path is found to an already visited node, but the number of hops is less, it should still be considered. This means that `came_from` is not a good structure now (as it only allows one path to pass via a node). Instead we can use a linked list (of back-references) that is included in the heap-element.

NB: I would also make `max_hop` a parameter to the function:

```py
from heapq import heappop, heappush

def dijkstra(adjList, source, sink, max_hop=8):  # make max_hop a parameter
    n = len(adjList)   
    least_hops = [n]*n  # Used for deciding whether to visit node via different path
    heap = [(0, 0, (source, None))]  # came_from is now a linked list: (a, (b, (c, None)))
    while heap:
        distance, hop_count, chain = heappop(heap)  # hop_count is part of tuple
        current = chain[0]
        if hop_count >= least_hops[current]:
            continue  # Cannot be an improvement
        least_hops[current] = hop_count
        if sink and current == sink:
            print("Hop count is ", hop_count)
            path = []
            while chain:
                current, chain = chain  # Unwind linked list
                path.append(current)
            return 1, distance, path[::-1]
        
        if hop_count >= max_hop:  # no recursion beyond max_hop
            print("Terminate")
            continue
        hop_count += 1  # Adjusted for next pushes unto heap
        for neighbor, cost in adjList[current]:
            heappush(heap, (distance + cost, hop_count, (neighbor, chain)))  # Prepend neighbor
```

As to your other question:

> How to determine Dijkstra has already found the shortest distance between a parent_node and a neighbor_node?

We don't determine this immediately and allow multiple paths to the same node to co-exist. The `if` in the `for` loop detects whether the node was already visited **and** the number of hops to it is not an improvement: this means it had received priority on the heap and had been pulled from it in an earlier iteration of the main `while` loop, and thus we already have a shortest path to that node. This `if` prevents us from pushing a useless "alternative" path on the heap: even if the shortest path needs to be rejected later because it cannot stay within the hop limit, an alternative that did not use fewer hops, cannot hope to then stay within the limit either, so it can be rejected now.

Comment: Very efficient code, and very nice explanation, thank you @trincot very much!

Comment: I don't think it'll always find the shortest path because of max hop termination.
See @Happy-Monad answer above for details

Comment: @trincot I mean there is no guarantee that among a number of routes that are within max number of hops the found path will be shortest if we use Dijkstra + max-hop-termination. That's what I found with my own code as well.
See Happy-Monad answer above for details

Comment: @trincot consider failing test case:
Need to find the shortest path from A to B with no more than 4 max hops(3 intermediate stops). Adjacency list:` "A": ("E", 1), ("D", 10),"E": ("F", 1),"F": ("G", 1),"G": ("H", 1),"H": ("B", 1),"D": ("G", 1)`
Shortest path is A->E->F->G->H->B if not limited by max hops (path1).
Shortest path is A->D->G->H->B if taking max hops into account(path2).
If we first go via path1: A->E->F->G->H-> terminate( A,E,F,G,H nodes will be marked as visited). 
If we then go via path2 after path1: A->D-> now G node is seen as visited and thus will not be added to heap.

Comment: Many thanks for putting that together, @Andrew! I see how the marking as visited is too strict. I have updated the answer to only reject a revisit when the number of hops is not improved by it. I am looking at your previous work on SO and see some good answers that need votes ;-)

Comment: Great, thanks
BTW, [here](https://github.com/tandryukha/routing-service/blob/65bcf1cb83613d181c5cf861265f1db81fdb6ba3/src/main/java/com/transporeon/routing/service/DPPathFinder.java#L35) is dynamic programming approach I used to address this problem

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions here, one is how to keep track of the length of the path and the other is terminating the program once the maximum path length is exceeded. Both have quite different answers.

On one hand, you can keep count of how many hops the shortest path has by just getting the length of the path after the algorithm finishes (though it doesn't seem to be what you want). Secondly, you might also keep track of how many hops are required to get from the source to any given node X at an arbitrary iteration, just keep track of the length of the current path from s to a vertex X and update the path-length of the neighbors at the relaxation step. This is greatly covered by @trincot answer which provides code too.

Now, before getting to the program termination part, let me state three useful lemmas that are invariant through Dijkstra Algorithm.

> Lemma 1: For every marked vertex, the distance from source to that vertex is a shortest path.
> Lemma 2: For every unmarked vertex, the current recorded distance is a shortest path considering only the already visited vertices.
> Lemma 3: If the shortest is s -> ... -> u -> v then, when u is visited and it's neighbor's distance updated the distance d(s, v) will remain invariant.

What these lemmas tell us is that:

1. When node X is marked as visited then: d(s, x) is minimal and the length of the path s->x will remain invariant (from Lemma 1)
2. Until node X is marked as visited d(s, x) is an estimate and the length of the path s->x is whatever the current path length is. Both values might change. (from Lemma 2)
3. You can't guarantee that a path of length N is a shortest path nor guarantee that the shortest path has length <= N (From Lemma 3 with a bit of work)

Therefore, if you decide to terminate the program when the path-length from source to sink is greater than a maximum hops number the information obtained can't be guaranteed to be optimal. In particular, any of these may happen at program termination:

- The path length is N but there is another path of length N with shorter distance.
- The path length is N and there is another path of minor length and shorter distance.

If you want to get the shortest path from source to sink while putting a limit on the path length you should use the [Bellman-Ford](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/bellman_ford.html) algorithm instead, which guarantees that at each iteration `i` all path have length of at most `i` edges and that this path is shortest with that constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the profound explanation. You're right. It can work but not in all cases.
Example of failing test case:
`A->B, maxHops=4(3 intermediate stops),adjacencyList: "A": ("E", 1), ("D", 10),"E": ("F", 1),"F": ("G", 1),"G": ("H", 1),"H": ("B", 1),"D": ("G", 1)`

Answer (score -2):

This code is using prioirty queue for dijkstra algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#define limit 15

using namespace std;

int cost[20001];
vector<int> plist[20001];

const int MaxVal = -1;

vector< vector< pair<int, int> > > arr;

struct node {
    pair<int, int> info;
    vector<int> path;
};

bool operator < (node a, node b) {
    return a.info.first > b.info.first;
}

int main() {
    int i, j, k;
    int n, m;
    int s;
    int a, b, c;
    cin >> n >> m;
    cin >> s;
    //arr.reserve(n + 1);
    arr.resize(n + 1);

    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        arr[a].push_back({ b, c });
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cost[i] = MaxVal;
    }

    priority_queue<node, vector<node>> mh;
    mh.push(node{ { 0, s }, { } });
    while (mh.size() > 0) {
        int current = mh.top().info.second;
        int val = mh.top().info.first;
        auto path = mh.top().path;
        mh.pop();
        if (cost[current] != MaxVal) continue;//All path would be sorted in prioirty queue. And the path that got out late can't be the shorter path.
        cost[current] = val;
        path.push_back(current);
            if(path.size() > limit) {
                //limit exceeded!! 
                cout << "limitation exceeded!!";
                break;
            }
        plist[current] = path;
        for (auto it : arr[current]) {
            if (cost[it.first] != MaxVal) continue;
            mh.push({ { it.second + val, it.first }, path });
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cout << "path to " << i << " costs ";
        if (cost[i] == MaxVal) {
            cout << "INF\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << cost[i] << "\n";
        }
        for (auto p : plist[i]) {
            cout << p << " ";
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
    }   

    return 0;
}

//test case
15 55
1 //Starting Node Number
1 2 3
1 4 11
1 5 5
2 1 3
2 3 5
2 5 11
2 6 7
3 2 5
3 6 3
4 1 11
4 5 15
4 7 9
5 1 5
5 2 11
5 6 3
5 7 6
5 8 3
5 9 9
6 2 7
6 3 3
6 5 3
6 9 10
7 4 9
7 5 6
7 8 1
7 10 11
7 11 8
8 5 3
8 7 1
8 9 9
8 11 11
9 5 9
9 6 10
9 8 9
9 11 3
9 12 8
10 7 11
10 13 7
10 14 3
11 7 8
11 8 11
11 9 3
11 12 8
11 14 6
12 9 8
12 11 8
12 15 11
13 10 7
13 15 3
14 10 3
14 11 6
14 15 9
15 12 11
15 13 3
15 14 9

path to 1 costs 0
1

path to 2 costs 3
1 2

path to 3 costs 8
1 2 3

path to 4 costs 11
1 4

path to 5 costs 5
1 5

path to 6 costs 8
1 5 6

path to 7 costs 9
1 5 8 7

path to 8 costs 8
1 5 8

path to 9 costs 14
1 5 9

path to 10 costs 20
1 5 8 7 10

path to 11 costs 17
1 5 8 7 11

path to 12 costs 22
1 5 9 12

path to 13 costs 27
1 5 8 7 10 13

path to 14 costs 23
1 5 8 7 11 14

path to 15 costs 30
1 5 8 7 10 13 15
```

Comment: I don't think you covered what was asked. The OP already has implemented this.

Comment: @trincot sorry, my english is not good very well. I understood this question as finding method to count hop counts during the dijkstra searching. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I must be missing something in your code: where are you measuring the hop count and where are you terminating the search when a max hop count is exceeded?

Comment: Oh. My code doesnt terminate when after the limitation exceeded. It just counts hop counts.. I was missing there. I'll fix it. Thx.